# Java Won't Return Int Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a program where I'm creating 2 arrays, inserting 10 random numbers into one array, then using copyArray to copy the info from the first array into the second, then returning that and displaying it.

```
`class C9e5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        int[] b = new int[10];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
           a[i] = r.nextInt();
        }
        copyArray(a, b);
        System.out.println("Array a contains " + a);
        System.out.println("Array b contains " + b);
    }
    public static int copyArray(int[] c, int[] d)
    {
        c = d;
        return c;
        return d;
    }
}`
```

The error message popping up keeps saying "incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int"
What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

---

Okay so now it's working (thank you everyone!), but when I compile and run it, instead of getting random numbers I'm getting random symbols.  Please help!

Comment: Why are you returning c and d? change the return type to int[ ] in your method signature.

Answer (score 2):

For your array copy to work, you need to actually copy the values from `c` to `d` (because you cannot update the caller's reference).

```
public static void copyArray(int[] c, int[] d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        d[i] = c[i];
    }
}
```

**Or**, something like

```
public static int[] copyArray(int[] c) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(c, c.length);
}
```

and then use it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[10];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = r.nextInt();
    }
    int[] b = copyArray(a);
    // Arrays don't override toString...
    System.out.println("Array a contains " + Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println("Array b contains " + Arrays.toString(b));
}
```

Comment: Be careful of the first copy method with the for loop. It isn't checking that `d` has the correct length. It could throw an exception or have weird results.

Answer (score 1):

Your copyArray method is invalid. It is trying to return an int array in the code but the method signature declares that it returns a regular int. Also the second return is dead code...it can never be run.